# Is there any other ways except wizard to import xls table into mysql Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, xls

I am creating a big data with 9k rows and all that I have in XLS format witch is impossible to import through Wizard into the Workbench. I tried this

- save into another Forman and import (Gives me an error)
- importing as a row inside the tables (too big data impossible)
- converted into CSV file with doc format(doest work same error as first try)

So what are other tools to do that. 
My final wish is to upload two big tables both 9k rows and to match them all together.
I know how to match and do the rest, but stacked completely in the importing point.

I expect after Importing to see all my xls table in SQL workbench so I can match it to the other one that I have. I am using last version of SQLWB and Libre Office. My machine is MAC

5th day and still zero result... never ever had such problems.

Comment: export to csv, load data infile, do stuff...? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: 9K rows is a small table, not a big table (big==six or seven figure row count). The tools you use should have no trouble with that size of table.  Almost no data-upload tools read .xlsx files directly, so you should use Calc's Save As... to save your data as a Text CSV file type before proceeding. MySQL Workbench generally gives error messages when it fails to convert; please [edit] your question to show those messages.

Comment: When I am trying to import with the help of wizard an csv file it says this error 

Unhandled exeption: new-line character seen in unquoted filed.

if I try to import with rows 
Number of fields in pasted data doest't match the columns in the table (1 vs 3)data must be in the same format by the Copy Row Content command.

Comment: Also I have 10 columns in my table but I need only 3 of them to match with another 9ktable its name id and phone

Maybe I have to create 10 columns for the data that I am receiving ?

Comment: like I think I have to create in mysqlWB for each column in table a column in mysqlWB? or it is not necessary.? please